# Calculate Rank with points

Tags: php, mysql, rank

I have a database with users and points (in fact it's a percentage, but that doesn't matter). The user(s) with the highest number of points is on the first rank, the second on the second rank ...

I could get the rank of a `$searchedUserID` if I did somethink like this:

```sql
SELECT `user_id`, `points` FROM `usertable` ORDER BY `points` DESC
```

```php
/** This function returns the rank of a user. The rank nr. 1 is the best.
 *  It is possible that some users share a rank.
 *
 * @param int $searchedUserID the ID of the user whose rank you would like to 
 *                            know
 *
 * @return int rank
 */
function getUserRank($searchedUserID)
{
    $userArray = getAllUsersOrderedByPoints();
    $rank       = 0;
    $lastPoints = -1; // Never happens
    foreach ( $userArray as $user) {
        if ($user['point'] != $lastPoints)  $rank++;
        if ($user['user_id'] == $searchedUserID) break;
    }
    return $rank;
}
```

Isn't there a more direct way to get this with (My)SQL? 
If not: Can the PHP-part be improved?

(edit: I could store the rank calculated by PHP directly in the database ... but this would mean I had to make quite a lot of UPDATEs.)

edit2: Perhaps `GROUP BY` could be used? Something like:

```sql
SELECT `user_id`, `points` FROM `usertable` GROUP BY `points` ORDER BY `points` DESC
```

The problem with this query is the possibility, that I don't get the searched user_id. It would be necessary to send a second query:

```sql
SELECT `user_id` FROM `usertable` WHERE `points` = $pointsOfTheUser
```

Comment: As a general rule its faster to sort your results in PHP than in mySQL.  If you do an `EXPLAIN` on your query with and without the `ORDER BY` with your final query you'll see what I mean.  This is something to consider when the dataset gets large.  Just my 2cp.

Comment: I like the `// Never happens`-comment ;)

Comment: @sjngm: This is important to know if the best rank should be one. If I would use negative rankings and the highest number was -1, the returned rank was 0. However, I have no idea why anybody should use negative points ;-)

Comment: @YzmirRamirez - *As a general rule its faster to sort your results in PHP than in mySQL.* I've never heard this before; do you have any more information? (And I'm not necessarily doubting you.)

Comment: @moose: You got me wrong. Comments like this are funny to read when e.g. they appear in some exception handling and the circumstances enforce catching the exception, but the coder "knows" that it will never ever be thrown. Then in production there is a situation where it *is* thrown... -- It hasn't got anything to do with your code, it's just funny.

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> *Isn't there a more direct way to get this with (My)SQL?*

Yes.  In SQL:2003, you could use the DENSE_RANK() window function.  In MySQL, you can simulate this, as the (dense) rank of a record by some score is simply the count + 1 of distinct better scores:

```
   SELECT u.user_id,
          u.points,
          1 + COUNT(DISTINCT others.points) AS `dense_rank`
     FROM users u
LEFT JOIN users others
          ON u.points < others.points  -- Which other users have more points?
    WHERE user_id = ?
 GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps an inner join with group by and sort would do the trick?

```
SELECT * FROM 
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT user_id AS uid, max(points) AS score 
    FROM usertable GROUP BY user_id
  )
AS ds ON usertable.user_id = ds.uid AND usertable.points = ds.score
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Just thinking on paper (pixels) .. wouldn't that give you the list in order from highest points to lowest with a unique record per user ... or are you looking to have these sorted where you can clarify a tie as a single "place" in the rankings?